# Using purrr and dplyr: is rlang::sym the best way

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang

I'd like to write functions that use dplyr verbs, which means I have to wade into the murky waters of `rlang`.

To provide a concrete example, say I want to use `purrr::map_df()` to iterate over  variables in a `dplyr::group_by()`. The [programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) vignette walks through writing a `my_summarise()` function; the approach there is to use `rlang::enquo()` on the grouping variable, then unquote with `!!`.
This approach works to make a new dplyr-like function that takes unquoted variable names (`my_summarise(df, g1)` in the vignette).

In contrast, I want to purrr provide the variable name as a string. Is `rlang::sym()` the right way to do this? It seems like it isn't, because `sym()` isn't mentioned in the dplyr programming vignette and barely mentioned in the rlang [tidy evaluation article](http://rlang.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-evaluation.html). Is there a better way?

```
library(tidyverse)
my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {
  group_var <- rlang::sym(group_var)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!group_var) %>%
    summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

# This works. Is that a good thing?
purrr::map_df(c("cyl", "am"), my_summarise, df = mtcars)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
    cyl   mpg    am
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  4.00  26.7 NA   
2  6.00  19.7 NA   
3  8.00  15.1 NA   
4 NA     17.1  0   
5 NA     24.4  1.00
```

As a follow-up, why does simply unquoting (without first applying `enquo` or `sym`) work some of the time?  In the example below, why does `select()` work as expected but `group_by()` doesn't?

```
x <- "cyl"
select(mtcars, !!x)
group_by(mtcars, !!x)
```

Update: the answer is not about unquoting. It's that `select` is more flexible and can handle strings, while `group_by` can't.

Other ref: This [blog post](https://edwinth.github.io/blog/dplyr-recipes/) by Edwin Thoen.

Comment: I'm just going to say that recently, using sym() has been solving all my seemingly unsolvable issues with quoting.  Sometimes `!!sym()` especially when there is an expression.  Also I think it would be better to break this into two questions.

Comment: The draft vignette does use `sym`. http://rpubs.com/lionel-/programming-draft

Comment: Thank you both, @Elin and @G-Grothendieck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

If you want to `map` over columns, `sym` is a fine way to do it. Lionel Henry demonstrates `sym` in the [draft vignette](https://rpubs.com/lionel-/programming-draft).

In cases where you want to pass a column name, but aren't trying to iterate, Kirill Müller [prefers](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3289#issuecomment-355922553) `quo`. In the example below, they have the same effect.

```
library(dplyr)

x <- rlang::quo(cyl)
y <- rlang::sym("cyl")
identical(group_by(mtcars, !!x), group_by(mtcars, !!y))  # TRUE
```

Comment: With rlang >=0.4.0, this has gotten easier. Use `group_by(.data[[x]])` if `x` is a string. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/