# Change iteration number in one Dplyr command

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I need to be able to change iteration number in each seperated line of one dplyr code.
I have prepared and example of 'by hand' approach and what I need to do in 'pseudo steps'.

```
library(tidyverse)

cr <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest()


# This is 'by-hand' approach of what I would like to do - How to automate it? E.g. we do not know all values of 'carb'

cr$data[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(VARIABLE1 = 
           case_when(carb == 1 ~ hp/mpg,
                          TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(VARIABLE2 = 
          case_when(carb == 2 ~ hp/mpg,
                         TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(VARIABLE4 =
          case_when(carb == 4 ~ hp/mpg,
                         TRUE ~ 0))

# This is a pseodu-idea of what I need to do. Is the any way how to change iteration number in ONE dplyr code?

vals <- cr$data[[1]] %>% pull(carb) %>% sort %>% unique()

for (i in vals) {
  message(i)

cr$data[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(paste('VARIABLE', i, sep = '') =  case_when(carb == i ~ hp/mpg, # At this line, all i shall be first element of vals
                          TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  mutate(paste('VARIABLE', i, sep = '') =  case_when(carb == i ~ hp/mpg, # At this line, all i shall be second element of vals
                          TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  mutate(paste('VARIABLE', i, sep = '') =  case_when(carb == i ~ hp/mpg, # At this line, all i shall be third element of vals
                                                            TRUE ~ 0))
                

}
```

is there any trick maybe using `purrr` package or other solution as well?
I need to iterate over some unique values of some variable. And for each unique value create a new column in dataframe. I need to automatize this, however I am not able to do so on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `sym` to convert text to symbols and `!!` to evaluate within dplyr functions. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131597/using-purrr-and-dplyr-is-rlangsym-the-best-way) and [this vignette](https://rpubs.com/lionel-/programming-draft) for further details.

For your application, you probably want something like this:

```r
carbs = c(1,2,4)

for(cc in carbs){
  var_name = sym(paste0("VARIABLE",cc))

  cr$data[[1]] =   cr$data[[1]] %>%
    mutate(!!var_name := case_when(carb == cc ~ hp/mpg,
                                         TRUE ~ 0))
}
```

There are three key parts to this:

1. `sym` turns the text string into a symbol variable.
2. `!!` means that a symbol is treated as an R expression
3. `:=` lets us use `!!` evaluation on the left-hand-side of the equation